# How to watch char values of strings pointed by a pointer to pointers in debugger mode of VSCode

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

## Let's say I'm working with this C program.

- I have three strings that's stored in dynamically allocated memory.
- I'm storing the addresses to those strings in dynamically allocated pointer to pointers variable.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char    *p0 = strdup("red..");
    char    *p1 = strdup("green");
    char    *p2 = strdup("blue.");
    char    *p3 = NULL;
    char    **pp = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 4); /* I want to watch this in VSCode debugger */

    pp[0] = p0;
    pp[1] = p1;
    pp[2] = p2;
    pp[3] = p3;

  /* do something */

    return (0);
}
```

## What I want to achieve

In the watch view of VSCode debugger, how do I get it to display the char values (and addresses if possible) of the strings pointed by each pointers like the following?

```
<watch_expression_for_pp>: <address of pp>
   |- pp[0]: [6] <address of pp[0]>
   |     |--- [0]: 'r'
   |     |--- [1]: 'e'
   |     |--- [2]: 'd'
   |     |--- [3]: '.'
   |     |--- [4]: '.'
   |     |--- [5]: '\0'
   |
   |- pp[1]: [6] <address of pp[1]>
   |     |--- [0]: 'g'
   |     |--- [1]: 'r'
   |     |--- [2]: 'e'
   |     |--- [3]: 'e'
   |     |--- [4]: 'n'
   |     |--- [5]: '\0'
   |
   |- pp[2]: [6] <address of pp[2]>
   |     |--- [0]: 'b'
   |     |--- [1]: 'l'
   |     |--- [2]: 'u'
   |     |--- [3]: 'e'
   |     |--- [4]: '.'
   |     |--- [5]: '\0'
   |
   |- pp[3]: [6] <0x0000000000000000>
         |--- [0]: 'r'
         |--- [1]: 'a'
         |--- [2]: 'n'
         |--- [3]: 'd'
         |--- [4]: 'o'
         |--- [5]: 'm'
```

## What I already know

I know that if I add `(char(*)[6])pp[0]` as an watch expression, I will be able to view the 6 char values from `pp[0][0]` to `pp[0][5]`, but that's not an ideal solution if I'm dealing with hundreds of pointers and need to go through the values quickly.

[image: watch char values of a single string]

I'm looking for a way to add one watch expression, and be able to get a view like above, just like when I'm watching a linked list in the debugger.
Or, a completely different approach, like using an extension.

Comment: `that's not an ideal solution if I'm dealing with hundreds of pointers and need to go through the values quickly` at that level modify your program to produce a log during its execution, may be under a condition on the value of a variable you set through your debugger, but do you really want to check by eyes hundreds of pointers/strings ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I agree.
You're saying that I should make use of conditional breakpoints, correct?

Comment: yes and no, you can have a global variable *V* valuing 0 by default and somewhere in the code `if (V) { ...debug printing or something else... }` and when needed though your debugger you change *V* value or putting a breakpoint on the test force PC to do the if body etc

Comment: @bruno To watch a global variable in VSCode debugger, you need to manually add a watch expression in the watch view. But the values of the variables that has been added to the watch view cannot be modified by the user during debugging.
I kind of understand the technique you're trying to explain, but not fully. I also don't understand what you mean by "test force PC". I would appreciate it if you could give me a more detailed explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I never used that debugger but looking at its documentation I can see when the program is stopped (breakpoint ...) you are able to modify the value of a variable through the Set Value action from the variable's context menu . PC contains the address of the next instruction to execute, it is common for a debugger to allow to modify it to continue the execution elsewhere than the next instruction on  breakpoint, so in tha case I speak about to not do `if (V)` (which is false) but to continue at the beginning of the body of the if.

Comment: @bruno Yes, you can set values of LOCAL variables when the program hits a breakpoint, but that doesn't seem to be possible with GLOBAL variables. There's no context menu for it.
[https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9722#issuecomment-235210676][https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9722#issuecomment-235210676]
I understood what you meant about the program counter now, thanks. I'll do a research on that topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
(char (*(*)[4])[6])pp
```

[image]

As you can see, you were already really close!

Of course, the strings you use may not have a fixed size so the second dimension `[6]` would not be accurate and should probably match the longest string that you expect. Hence for shorter strings, you might see some gibberish from the adjacent memory locations.

**Edit:**
As I later figured out, you can also drop the second dimension and use this much cleaner version:

```
(char (*(*)[N]))pp
```

where `N` is the number of strings you have in your array.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.
I want to confirm one thing to make sure that I'm understanding this correctly.
If I were to describe this type casting in an English sentence, it would be:
"Type cast pp to a pointer to an array of 4 pointers to an array of 6 chars.".
Correct?

Comment: @KIYZ Yes, that is exactly what it means. Although, as I later realized, you can drop the second dimension and have just: `(char (*(*)[4]))pp`, which works as well!